# Which linux distro ships unaltered GNOME 3.1x

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, distribution-choice

I tried the GNOME 3.14 promo DVD. Unfortunately it did not offer the option to install it. I would like to install the latest version of GNOME that ships in a Linux distribution, which I suppose is 3.10 as of today.

However I would like unaltered/vanilla GNOME desktop, by which I mean among others:

- no distribution-specific baggage/cruft/themes/logos/banners/..., or at least it should be removable by uninstalling a single/few software-repository-packages
- should ship with GNOME's default web browser called Web, not Firefox nor Chrome

Which (mainstream) distribution offers this?

Comment: The browser was formerly known as Epiphany. And, Arch ships the package virtually vanilla afaik. Also, the latest is 3.14 now iirc.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora is one distro that I'm aware of that includes default versions of GNOME 3.x. Fedora 20 comes with 3.10:

- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Gnome3.10

And they typically roll with newer versions as they come out. Fedora 21 will likely come with 3.14.

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/21/Schedule?rd=Releases/21

*excerpt*

> Links to other significant project schedules--useful for seeing how Fedora 
>   aligns with them.
>
> - Gnome 3.14 -- [September 24, 2014](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointThirteen)
> - KDE 4.14 -- [August 13, 2014](https://techbase.kde.org/Schedules/KDE4/4.14_Release_Schedule)
>
> Feel free to add any other significant projects schedules!

There's also a link to the main distros that carry GNOME here on GNOME project's page:

- http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/

Comment: unfortunately I remember Fedora to be a pile of bugs

Comment: I've used it as my primary OS since FC1, I'm on 19 and 20 now, so everyone's entitled to their opinion, but it works just fine. BTW, every distro has it's issues, I support Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, CentOS 5, 6, F19, F20, and they all have their issues. Don't believe the hype,they're all evolving s/w and so have to be tended to like a garden. Same with Windows + OSX. It's the nature of software.

Comment: @slm [this comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159678/which-linux-distro-ships-unaltered-gnome-3-1x/159685?noredirect=1#comment261719_159685) is very appropriate here as well. :)

Comment: @muru - yes it is 8-)

Comment: There's also distrowatch. You can search for what distros have GNOME on their advanced search page: http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=All&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=GNOME&architecture=All&status=Active. This search shows dozens of distros to choose from.

Comment: @slm that Fedora had so many bugs in two consecutive releases (18 and 19 if I remember correctly) was the reason I stayed with Ubuntu this long. Ubuntu LTS releases do not have noticably many bugs. The distrowatch link helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Arch Linux usually has vanilla GNOME, and [3.14 is in `testing`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=gnome-shell&maintainer=&flagged=) now. Since you install whatever you want in Arch, and very little is installed by default in the `base`, this is pretty close.

Comment: Isn't Arch the kind of distro requiring you to browse forums for workarounds and script to get things working?

Comment: @peterf - that's every OS.

Comment: @peterf That depends. I have only been to the Arch Linux forums about thrice in the three years I have used it. The Arch Wiki is one of the best sources of documentation around (a lot of it applicable to other distros as well). The [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide) covers about everything you need to get it up and running.

Comment: I'm always referencing the ArchLinux documentation and don't even use it. But I now that distro comes highly recommended by many on this site too.